# BATCH: Syntax for using IF Exist to a remote machine inside of a For Loop (For /L)

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file

I am trying to put an If Exist statement inside of a for loop. The goal for this batch script is check if a file exists on all of the devices on my network. The output I keep getting is "The system could not find the file specified.

Here is what I have so far, any help would be much appreciated:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query 
"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces"  /V IPaddress /s ^|findstr /ri 
"REG_MULTI_SZ"') do set localip=%%a

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%a in ("%localip%") do (
set octetA=%%a
set octetB=%%b
set octetC=%%c
set octetD=%%d
)
FOR /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%offsets%") do (
SET /a octetA+=%%a
SET /a octetB+=%%b
SET /a octetC+=%%c
SET /a octetD+=%%d
)


for /L %%i in (1,1,255) do @if exist 
"\\%octetA%.%octetB%.%octetC%.%%i\C$\Folder\file.txt"
Echo File exists
) else (
Echo File does not exist
)
```

Comment: Quote the whole path rather than components, and remove the line-break behind `if exist`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do that like this from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bsh
@For /F Tokens^=2* %%G In ('^""%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Query ^
 "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces" /S ^
 /F IPAddress /C /E /V 2^> NUL ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" ^
 "IPAddress "^"') Do @For /L %%I In (1 1 255) Do @Echo Checking %%~nH.%%I ^
 & If Exist "\\%%~nH.%%I\C$\Folder\file.txt" (Echo File exists
) Else Echo File does not exist
```

*Please add a line `@Pause` as a new last line, if not running this directly from the Command Prompt.*

The above is really only a single line command, split over a few, for easier reading. If you wanted to run it as a single line, from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).exe, you could use this:

```bsh
@For /F Tokens^=2* %G In ('^""%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces" /S /F IPAddress /C /E /V 2^> NUL ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" "IPAddress "^"') Do @For /L %I In (1 1 255) Do @Echo Checking %~nH.%I & If Exist "\\%~nH.%I\C$\Folder\file.txt" (Echo File exists) Else Echo File does not exist
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm also trying to find a way for it to grab the IP from a specific NIC if a machine has two. Any ideas there would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Batch is an ancient language, to which facilities have been added over the years. Adding facilities is a problem since the syntax chosen should both accommodate existing structures and unambiguously implement the new.

Originally, there was no "else" facility - just `if somecondition dosomething`.

When `else` was added, the general syntax of the `if` statement was changed to

```
if somecondition (dosomething) else (dosomethingelse)
```

where the `else` clause is optional and the parentheses could include a sequence of commands, each on separate lines.

Hence, it is syntactically-correct to include line breaks after the `(` and *only* after `(`. Therefore the correct structure is

```
if somecondition (
 dosomething
 andanotherthing
 thensomethingelse with these parameters
) else (
 dosomethingelse
 andthat
 andsomethingelse&yetanotherthing
)
```

Note that `&` is another enhancement to separate multiple commands to be executed on one physical line.

The syntax is very definitely **NOT** free-form.

So - the `(` *MUST* appear on the same physical line as the `if` and potentially starts a statement-sequence terminated by `)` and the `else` keyword *AND* its `(` (if used) *MUST* appear on the same physical line as that terminal `)`.

Consequently,

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,255) do @if exist 
"\\%octetA%.%octetB%.%octetC%.%%i\C$\Folder\file.txt"
Echo File exists
) else (
Echo File does not exist
)
```

requires `"\\%octetA%.%octetB%.%octetC%.%%i\C$\Folder\file.txt"` to be on the same *PHYSICAL* line as the `exist` (not freeform, so you can't break the conditional clause `exists filename`) *AND* there must be a `(` on the same physical line to commence the statement-sequence to be executed on condition-true because you are using an `else` clause.

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,255) do @if exist "\\%octetA%.%octetB%.%octetC%.%%i\C$\Folder\file.txt" (
Echo File exists
) else (
Echo File does not exist
)
```